# VAR in differences

Tags: r, var

can any one help me?if i have a multivariate time series consisting of 4 time series out of which one is non stationery and needs to be differenced one to make it stationery, while others are already stationery. what type of VAR model should i use? VAR in levels or VAR in differences? if i difference the whole multivariate time series once and fit some VAR(p), and find some forecasts, how to get back to the forecasts of original levels instead of forecasts of differenced series.
Also how can i check for cointegration? i am working in R. Any help in R is appritiated.
thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question, anyway you can start by reading the documentation of the [`vars` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the VAR model for Canada is:

```
VAR in differences <=> Yt=(diff(rw), diff(prod), diff(e), diff(U))
```

You should  read a book of Bernhard Pfaff "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R" and do some code (on website "http://www.pfaffikus.de/springerex2.html") to get a VARs model for Canada data-set in vars package of R language.